# Passing argument inside React.createElement()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am trying to pass argument name in `React.createElement()` and I failed. And I want to use JSX only. Here is my code:

```
const Main = (props) => {
    return React.createElement(
    'div',
    null,
    React.createElement('h1', {props.name})
    )
}
```

Comment: just give props.name

Comment: try `{ name: props.name }`

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to createElement is the props we are passing to the component and third argument is the children, here `props.name` needs to be the child of h1 tag

```js
React.createElement('h1', null, props.name);
```

You can verify this from the online babel compiler

[Online babel compiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?presets=react&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwKYBt1wBQEpEDeAUIogE6pQhlIA8AJjAG4B8AEhlogO5xnr0AhLQD0jVgG4iAXyJA)

[image]